# Raw binary midi stream in terminal?

Tags: terminal, midi, binary

I want to be able to cat the device file of a raw binary input stream from a midi controller. In Ubuntu, the process to do this was something like `cat /dev/dmmidi1`. However, I do not see such a file in OS X. There are, however, many more tty files than in ubuntu.

Is there a device file that I can cat, or do I have to get the raw midi stream from something else? How do I get the raw binary stream?